# Typescript: Require all keys in enum for valid type

Tags: typescript, types, enums

In Typescript, I have an enum as follows:
`enum User { Bob = "Bob", Sally = "Sally" }`

I would like to ensure that a new type defines a boolean for each enum value:

```
type UserActiveMap {
   User.Bob: boolean
   User.Sally: boolean
}
```

However, I don't want to list each enum value.
I know I can use `keyof typeof` but I'm not sure how to define the type to ensure this behavior:

```
type UserActiveMap {
   keyof typeof User: boolean
} // wrong
```

The practical implementation I'm shooting for is:

```
const rightMap: UserActiveMap = { User.Bob = true, User.Sally = false } // valid
const wrongMap: UserActiveMap = { User.Bob = false } // invalid - missing Sally
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was close with the syntax, but what I was looking for was:

```
type UserActiveMap {
   [K in keyof typeof User]: boolean
}
```

Now, I can implement with:

```
const MyMap = { User.Bob = true } // invalid type - missing Sally
```